# Hot to get the text of the selected option in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

`td` is a jQuery variable that references a table cell `<td>` element. This cell contains a `<select>` element which contains a number of `<option>` elements; each has a text and value.

This code returns the value (not text) of the selected option.

```
td.children().val();
```

I tried many ways to get the text of the selected option, but non of them work.

`td.children().text()` This returns the text of all the options of the `<select>` element.

I filtered it many ways but no result returned at all:
`td.children(':selected').text()`
`td.children('option:selected').text()`
`td.children('[selected]').text()`
`td.children('[selected=""]').text()`
`td.children('option[selected=""]').text()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `option` is immediate child of `select` not `td` the function `children()` will not work. Thus none of your attempted solution worked.

You need to use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

```
td.find('option:selected').text()
```

> The `.find()` and `.children()` methods are similar, except that the latter only travels a single level down the DOM tree.